# if Few fields of form are filled then other fields are not required angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a single form with 4 fields for say name1,address1,name2,address2which are all marked as required. Now I want if name1 and address1 are filled then name2 and address2 should not be marked as required and vice versa in angular..

I have tried dirty also but its not working accurately..

Comment: Can you show your code ? Are you using ngModels, or Reactive Forms ?

Comment: You can toggle validation for last two options based on first two value.